# Adding up numbers depending on textual entries in XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<variablelist>
    <varinfo id="id-5">
        <vardef>
            <name>A</name>
            <init>
                <compoundinit type="composite">
                    <singleinit>(unsigned char)6</singleinit>
                    <singleinit>(unsigned char)0</singleinit>
                    <compoundinit type="array">
                        <singleinit>(short)400</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)600</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)800</singleinit>
                    </compoundinit>
                    <compoundinit type="array">
                        <singleinit>(short)32767</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)32767</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)32767</singleinit>
                    </compoundinit>
                </compoundinit>
            </init>
        </vardef>
    </varinfo>
    <varinfo id="id-10">
        <vardef>
            <name>B</name>
            <init>
                <compoundinit type="array">
                    <singleinit>(uint32 const volatile)0U</singleinit>
                    <singleinit>(uint32 const volatile)0U</singleinit>
                    <singleinit>(uint32 const volatile)0U</singleinit>
                    <singleinit>(uint32 const volatile)0U</singleinit>
                </compoundinit>
            </init>
        </vardef>
    </varinfo>
    <varinfo id="id-200">
        <vardef>
            <name>C</name>
            <init>
                <compoundinit type="composite">
                    <singleinit>(unsigned char)12</singleinit>
                    <singleinit>(unsigned char)12</singleinit>
                    <compoundinit type="array">
                        <singleinit>(short)900</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)1000</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)1240</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)1750</singleinit>
                    </compoundinit>
                    <compoundinit type="array">
                        <singleinit>(short)512</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)640</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)853</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)1067</singleinit>
                        <singleinit>(short)1280</singleinit>
                    </compoundinit>
                    <compoundinit type="array">
                        <compoundinit type="array">
                            <singleinit>(unsigned char)153</singleinit>
                            <singleinit>(unsigned char)153</singleinit>
                            <singleinit>(unsigned char)153</singleinit>
                            <singleinit>(unsigned char)153</singleinit>
                        </compoundinit>
                        <compoundinit type="array">
                            <singleinit>(unsigned char)153</singleinit>
                            <singleinit>(unsigned char)153</singleinit>
                            <singleinit>(unsigned char)153</singleinit>
                            <singleinit>(unsigned char)153</singleinit>
                        </compoundinit>
                    </compoundinit>
                </compoundinit>
            </init>
        </vardef>
    </varinfo>
</variablelist>
```

What I want to do is to add up used bits of the variables. So variable A for example consists of 2 "unsigned char" and 6 "short" datatypes. Lets assume "short" equals 16 bit and "char" 8 bit. Thus variable A has 112 bit (6*16 + 2*8).

How would a XSLT file look like if I wanted the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<variablelist>
    <varinfo>
            <name>A</name>
            <size>112</size>
    </varinfo>
    <varinfo>
            <name>B</name>
            <size>128</size>
    </varinfo>
    <varinfo>
            <name>C</name>
            <size>224</size>
    </varinfo>
</variablelist>
```

At the moment I at least managed to achieve the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<variablelist>
   <varinfo>
      <name>A</name>
      <size>(unsigned char)6(unsigned char)0(short)400(short)600(short)800(short)32767(short)32767(short)32767</size>
   </varinfo>
   <varinfo>
      <name>B</name>
      <size>(uint32 const volatile)0U(uint32 const volatile)0U(uint32 const volatile)0U(uint32 const volatile)0U</size>
   </varinfo>
   <varinfo>
      <name>C</name>
      <size>(unsigned char)12(unsigned char)12(short)900(short)1000(short)1240(short)1750(short)512(short)640(short)853(short)1067(short)1280(unsigned char)153(unsigned char)153(unsigned char)153(unsigned char)153(unsigned char)153(unsigned char)153(unsigned char)153(unsigned char)153</size>
   </varinfo>
</variablelist>
```

With this transform code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <variablelist>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/variablelist"/>
        </variablelist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="variablelist">
        <xsl:for-each select="varinfo">
            <varinfo>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(current()/vardef/init)">
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:when test="current()/vardef/init">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="current()/vardef/init/singleinit">
                                <!-- ... -->
                            </xsl:when>

                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <name>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current()/vardef/name/."/>
                                </name>
                                <size>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="current()/vardef/init//node()">
                                        <xsl:if test="name() = 'singleinit'">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </size>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </varinfo>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For transformation of the strings to my numbers I would use something like this:

```
<xsl:when test="contains((substring-before((current()/vardef/init/singleinit/.),')')),'char')"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="'8'"/> 
</xsl:when>
```

Has anybody got an idea of how to solve my problem? I tried different ways via variables or parameters, but I was not successful so far.

Thanks!

PS.: First question asked here, hope I followed your netiquette correctly. And has somebody an idea of a better title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="varinfo">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="vardef/name"/>
            <size>
                <xsl:value-of select="8 *count( descendant::singleinit[ contains(.,'(unsigned char)') ] ) +
                            16 * count( descendant::singleinit[ contains(.,'(short)') ] ) +
                            32 *count( descendant::singleinit[ contains(.,'(uint32 const volatile)' ) ] )"/>
            </size>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<variablelist>
        <varinfo><name>A</name><size>112</size></varinfo>
        <varinfo><name>B</name><size>128</size></varinfo>
        <varinfo><name>C</name><size>224</size></varinfo>
</variablelist>
```

Comment: 
According your request: *For transformation of the strings to my numbers I would use something like this* (some xsl:when for bit size). 
I do not recommend that. This will only make things more complicated. Possible enhancements depending on your final solutions are:
 - Move the calculation into are named template.
 - adapt the contains operation that it dose not distinguish between signed and unsigned.

Comment: Thanks! And even much more compact than my way.
I will see into your suggestions about my string conversion.